# How to update RecyclerView in fragment inside TabLayout

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I have an activity with tow tabs(with viewPager). inside viewPager is a fragment that have RecyclerView.

first tab is for (Monday-Friday) and second tab is for (Saturday-Sunday)

I want to retrieve data from database and show in recyclerview on each tab. but i cant update my recyclerView. Please help me to do that.And another problem is that when RecyclerView show data only show first row, but the number of rows in the table.like this:

10:06:00

10:06:00

10:06:00

10:06:00

10:06:00

10:06:00

here is my code:

this is my Fragment code:

```
public class toDastgheybFragment extends BaseFragment {


    private List<DatabaseModel> Times = new ArrayList<DatabaseModel>();
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    private View mView;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_to_dastgheyb, container, 
false);
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
        Times = databaseHelper.getAllUsers();
        mRecyclerView = mView.findViewById(R.id.myRecycler);
        mAdapter = new DataAdapter(Times);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new 
LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        return mView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayList<DatabaseModel> LineList = new ArrayList<>();
        LineList.clear();
        mAdapter = new DataAdapter(LineList);
        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
        final List<DatabaseModel> m = db.getAllUsers();
        if (m.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++) {
                LineList.add(m.get(i));
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
        db.close();
    }
}
```

and this is my DataHelper code:

```
 public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MetroDB";//name of the 
database
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "stationtime";//name for the 
table
    static String db_path = "/data/data/ir.shirazmetro/databases/";
    private static final String Station = "station";
    private static final String Time = "time";
    private static final String Line = "line";
    private final Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + 
TABLE_NAME + "(" + Station + " TEXT," + Time + " TEXT," + Line + " TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
{
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    private boolean checkExist() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        try {
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(db_path + DATABASE_NAME, null, 
SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
        return db != null;
    }

    private void copyDatabase() throws IOException {
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(db_path + 
DATABASE_NAME);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME + 
".db");
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myInput.close();
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
    }

    public void importIfNotExist() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkExist();
        if (!dbExist) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDatabase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void open() {
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(db_path + DATABASE_NAME, null, 
SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    public List<DatabaseModel> getAllUsers() {
        List<DatabaseModel> contactList = new ArrayList<DatabaseModel>();
        String whatStation = C.whatStation;
        String whatLine = C.whatLine;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT " + Time + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " 
WHERE " + Station + " LIKE '%" + whatStation + "%' AND " + Line + " LIKE '%" 
+ whatLine + "%'";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            do {
                DatabaseModel m = new DatabaseModel();
                m.setTime(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Time)));
                contactList.add(m);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }


        return contactList;
    }

}
```

and finally this is my activity code:

```
public class station extends BaseActivity {
Toolbar mToolbar;
private TabLayout tbLayout;
private ViewPager vPager;
RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_station);

    final DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    try {
        helper.importIfNotExist();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }
    mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.tlbr1);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        initView();
        setupWithViewPager();
        tbLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new 
TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

    }

}


public void line1(View view) {
    Intent line1 = new Intent(this, line1.class);
    startActivity(line1);
}

private void setupWithViewPager() {
    BasePagerAdapter basePagerAdapter = new BasePagerAdapter(this, 
getSupportFragmentManager());
    vPager.setAdapter(basePagerAdapter);
    tbLayout.setupWithViewPager(vPager);

}

private void initView() {
    vPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    tbLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    backBtn = findViewById(R.id.backBtn);


}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.backBtn:
            line1(view);
            return;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: You can use broadcast receiver on TabLayout  click and update recyceler view

Comment: I dont work with BroadcastReciver yet. would you please guide me how do that?

Comment: **Refer This links** [Link1](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts)
[Link2](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers.htm)